# Run Thread In background

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, background

I have looked around and found different ways of doing this, all of which seem to generate an error. Here is what I am trying to run. It's connecting to a server which is already running.
Any ideas on how to get this to work or change it so it does work?

```
String serverAddress = MainActivity.serverAddress;
int port = MainActivity.newport;
Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, port);
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);           
String getName=MainActivity.name;

// Process all messages from server, according to the protocol.
while (true) {
    String line = in.readLine();
    if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
        out.println(getName);
    }
    else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {
        //textField.setEditable(true);
    }
    else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
        mt.append(line.substring(8) + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you running this code and what are the errors? An `AsyncTask` would be a good idea. Run the network code in `doInBackground()` and update the `UI` on any of the other methods.

Comment: do all network operations using either thread-handler or asynctask

Answer (score 0):

What is it that aint working? Is it the code itself or do you need help on running this while(true) loop as a thread?

The while(true) loop will hog the main java thread so you wont be able to do any other operations outside of the while-loop. So first I would recommend to make the operations inside of the while-loop to a thread by either implement runnable or create an anonymous class and start the thread.

There are lots of examples on this: [Java - creating a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758411/java-creating-a-new-thread)

Hope this helps! Message me back if i interpreted your question wrong.